# How to use preg_match_all for this specific string?

Tags: php, regex

Can I use preg_replace_all to extract "this is my string" from

```
$this->translate("this is my string")
```

This is what I have so far:

```
preg_match_all("/_[_|e]\([\"|\']([^\"|\']+)[\"|\']\)/i", '$this->translate("this is my string")', array());
```

I want to get "**this is my string**" How can this be done?

Comment: use this `"([^"]*)"` regex.

Comment: Can you explain the criteria by which you need to make your selection? Will there always be a `$this->translate("` before the content you are trying to get and an `")` after?   Right now, your example is overly trivial since the string is hard-coded and a problem best suited to be solved by simple string manipulation.

Comment: Yes my string will always start from $this->translate(" before the content you are trying to get and an ") and I always want the encode part that is: before the content you are trying to get and an

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following regex :

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK6fX8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do without a regex, just use the `between` function (taken from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)):

```
<?php
    function after ($this, $inthat)
    {
        if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
    };
    function before ($this, $inthat)
    {
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this));
    };
    function between ($this, $that, $inthat)
    {
        return before ($that, after($this, $inthat));
    };

   echo between ("(\"", "\")", "\$this->translate(\"this is my string\")");
?>
```

Here is a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYUVhaWlseHZlcnM) output:

```
this is my string
```

Comment: The first sentence of your answer seems to imply that `between()` is a PHP function and it is not.  It is a user-defined function (as you show in the rest of your example).

Comment: @MikeBrant: Sorry it sounded like that. I removed the word "PHP" before function.

Answer (score 0):

Using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$a = '$this->translate("this is my string")';
echo explode('"', $a)[1];
```

Output:

```
this is my string
```